# removing model fields from third party apps in django

Tags: django, django-models

I had installed dj-places app into my django project to have PlacesField() to autocomplete the locations field in my model. It did not work as expected. I uninstalled the app and changed the field to models.CharField().
The problem is whenever I am trying to make further migrations I am getting an error.

```
      posts\migrations\0007_auto_20200709_1445.py", line 4, in <module>
      import places.fields
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'places'
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Why not install the package, but do not include it in the `app_settings`. then the `PointField` is still supported in the migration files. As an alternative you can edit the migration files and remove the fields with the `PlaceField`, etc. but it can be a bit tricky to edit all the future migrations where you added/updated/... these fields.

Comment: yes this approach is working well. Thanks @Willem Van Onsem

Answer (score 0):

If you pip install the app then you can run `makemigrations` and `migrate` then pip uninstall the app again. This should work.